# Contradiction in calculating electric field outside of a dielectric material embedded with free charges

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, vector-fields

Let's say we have a region filled with a linear homogeneous dielectric, filled with some free charge density $\rho_{f}$ such that outside of this region the electric field is **zero**.

Then we can write **both inside and outside of this region** $$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{D}=\rho_{\rm f} \:\:\:{\rm and}\:\:\: \boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{D}=0$$Comparing it with the equations of electric field which would have been produced by free charges only,in the absence of dielectric
$$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{E}_{\rm vac}=\frac{\rho_{\rm f}}{\epsilon_{0}} \:\:\:{\rm and}\:\:\: \boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{E}_{\rm vac}=0$$ we deduce that$$
\mathbf{D}=\epsilon_{0} \mathbf{E}_{\text {vac}}
$$

But the final equation is wrong in the region outside of our dielectric. It's left hand side is zero ,since we began by assuming that the electric field is zero outside of the region, which implies $D=0$.
It's right hand side is non zero because we can choose $\rho_{f}$ to be such that $E_{\text {vac }}\neq0$ outside the dielectric.
Where is my logic wrong?

Comment: You can say that $\mathbf{D} = \epsilon_0 \mathbf{E}_{vac}$ when comparing the two equations with non zero $\rho_f$. But can you really say the same when the rhs of both the divergence equation is zero, which is true outside the dielectric?

Comment: I don't know. Is it wrong?